# NHibernate: Can I access a generated primary key after saving a model?

Tags: nhibernate

So I've got a simple table with an ID field that's incrementally generated on INSERT.

I've set the mapping up in NHibernate to reflect this:

```
<id name="ID">
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>
```

And it all works fine.

Trouble is, I need to get the generated ID after I've saved a new model to use elsewhere:

```
var model = new MyModel();
session.SaveOrUpdate(model);
```

But at this stage model.ID == null, not the ID.

Any ideas?

Anthony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to flush the session so that changes are persisted to the database. You can do this by calling `session.Flush()` or, better yet, using a transaction:

```
using (var txn = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    session.SaveOrUpdate(model);
    txn.Commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the identities are generated by the database, and since SaveOrUpdate() does not actually save your Model, the ID will be null. This should change once you commit the content of your session to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `Name` property in mappings then NHibernate will set Id for you after it saves entity

Answer (score 0):

after saving the primary key is accessable either because it generated clientside or when using identity it will issue an insert immediatly

```
var model = new MyModel();

var id = session.Save(model);
// or
session.SaveOrUpdate(model);
var id = model.Id;
```